# Is the proof of the claim correct? Is the claim true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

We say that an integer a is divisible by the nonzero integer b, if a = bc for some integer c: When a is divisible by b, we write b | a and say b divides a.

Claim: Let a and b be nonzero integers. If a | b and b | a, then a = b.

[image]

Comment: The claim is false (and hence, so is the proof).  The issue is when you go from $1 = k_1 k_0$ to $k_0 = k_1 = 1$ - there is *another* solution to this!  (I don't have time to write a full solution - anyone who wants to should feel free!)

Comment: In short, $a\mid b$ and $b \mid a$ if and only if $a = \pm b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false: $2\mid (-2)$ and $(-2)\mid 2$. I hope you agree that $2\ne-2$. The error in the proof is when from $k_0k_1=1$ you argue $k_0=1$. It might be $k_0=k_1=-1$.

The claim would be true if *natural* numbers are considered, rather than integers. The “nonzero” clause is not needed.

If $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, with $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then we have
$$
b=ax,\quad a=by
$$
whence
$$
a=axy
$$
We have two cases:

1. If $a=0$, then $ax=b=0$, so $a=b$.
2. If $a\ne0$, from $a=axy$ we deduce $xy=1$, so $x=y=1$, therefore $a=by=b$.

Adapt to that style of proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to read. A simpler approach would be to show that for positive integers, if $a$ divides $b$ then $a\leq b$. Doing this twice establishes the result.

Comment: True, this would establish the result for *positive* integers, but the OP is attempting to prove that the result holds for all *nonzero* integers, which is false.